# Odoo - Field `product_variant_count` does not exist

Tags: model, field, odoo

I have created a custom model called Product_Videos that will hold multiple video for one product, Here is my model :
from odoo import models, fields, api

```
class Product_Videos(models.Model):
    _name = "product.videos"

    embed_id = fields.Char(string='Embed Code Id')
    product_id = fields.Many2one("product.template", "Product")
```

I then inherited the product model to relate to Product_Videos:
from odoo import models, api, fields

```
class Product(models.Model):
    _inherit = "product.template"

    # Tab Fields
    x_videos = fields.One2many("product.videos", "product_id", "Videos")
```

Now I inherited the product template view and added a new tab called videos as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="product.tabs-inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.template.tabs</field>
            <field name="model">product.template</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//page[@name='notes']" position="after">
                    <page string="Videos" name="videos">
                        <field name="x_videos"/>
                    </page>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>  
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Now on the new tab, It only shows the Id of the video on the treeview, I want it to show other fields such as embed code, so I inherited the last view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<odoo>
        <record id="product-video-inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.video.embed</field>
            <field name="model">product.videos</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.tabs-inherited" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//page[@name='videos']" position="inside">
                    <field name="embed_id" />
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>  
</odoo>
```

But when I upgrade the module, I'm getting :

> Field `product_variant_count` does not exist

I have no idea where this product_variant_count field comes from, but I noticed that if I replace

```
<field name="model">product.videos</field>
```

With another model such as **product.template** It works just fine.

Any ideas ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply an xml view inheritance in Odoo, that means(normally) that the new view will inherit an existing view of the same model. So your view `product-video-inherited` need to be defined for the model `product.template` to work as you expect.

To be able to define what fields of the model `product.videos` will be visibles on the o2m field `x_videos` you could define a subview like:

```
    <record id="product.tabs-inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.template.tabs</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//page[@name='notes']" position="after">
                <page string="Videos" name="videos">
                    <field name="x_videos">
                        <tree>
                            <field name="embed_id"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </page>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Or you could define a tree view for the model `product.videos` that no inherit from any other view to define what all the default tree views will display for the model `product.videos`.

Comment: That was what I'm missing, thank you.
About your second suggestions, I tried to define a view model like containing a form + a tree like this (next comment) :

Comment: <record id="product-video-inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.video.embed</field>
            <field name="model">product.videos</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Video"> 
                    <field name="embed_id" context="{'default_product_id': id}" />
                </form>
                <tree string="Video List">
                    <field name="embed_id" />
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record> 
But It had no effect on the tree view, any idea why ?

Comment: Because you can't define 2 views on the same record.

Comment: Got it, separated the views in two different records and now It's working perfectly, Thank you for your time